# Problema no Retorno do JsonModel

Tags: zend, zend-framework-2

Estou desenvolvendo uma App utilizando Zend Framework 2 e Angular.js.

Eu tenho um módulo API Rest e utilizo, também, um módulo padrão retornando JsonModel de coisas mais especificas (o problema mora ai).

No meu module.config.php, configurei meu view_manager dessa forma:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'portal/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/portal/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy'
    )
),
```

Durante um tempo de desenvolvimento, se eu (na minha controller) fizesse isso:

```
...
return new JsonModel(array('teste'=>true));
...
```

Ele retornaria um JSON assim:

```
{"teste":true}
```

Só que não sei por qual motivo ele começou a retornar assim:

```
{"children":[],"options":[],"template":"portal-admin\/transportadora\/verifica-cnpj-cadastrado","terminate":true,"variables":{"teste":true},"append":false}
```

Já dei uma olhada na referência da classe no site da Zend e não consegui achar uma solução.

Alguém sabe como resolver essa situação?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, o problema estava na minha controller.

Eu tenho uma BaseController em que todas as outras controllers são "extendidas" dela. O problema se deu quando eu criei essa controller. Eu estendi ela da AbstractRestFulController, ao invés de estender da classe AbstractActionController.

Após destrocado os nomes, tudo funcionou corretamente!

Obrigado!

Comment: Faltou  marcar essa resposta como a solução da sua pergunta.

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado! Não tinha feito porque o stack não libera antes de 24 horas de pergunta.